# AttributeError: keras.backend ,no attribute 'eager'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using python 3.8.2  , keras 2.3.1 and tensorflow 2.2.0rc4  .
just with the following code :

```
import keras
from keras.models import sequential
```

I have this error :
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'eager' (most likely due to a circular import)

if I use :

```
import tensorflow
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras import ....
```

new error :

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'register_tensor_conversion_function' (most likely due to a circular import)

full traceback:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0WZ1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4rA8.png)

Comment: Could you try replacing `keras` with `tensorflow.keras` and see if the error is still there?

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: I have new error with tensorflow.keras ,,,  @RajSrujanJalem

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to reinstall the package. Sometimes this happens due to the installation problem.

Use the following code to do so

## Uninstall tensorflow

> pip uninstall tensorflow

## Requires the latest pip

> pip install --upgrade pip

## To install keras as separate package

> pip install Keras

## Current stable release for CPU and GPU

> pip install tensorflow

Try this and hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It's an install problem, most likely; `K.eager` was introduced in Keras 2.3.0 (and is included in Keras 2.3.1), so your Python interpreter is somehow reading code of 2.2.5 or earlier.

A possible culprit is an Anaconda mishap. First run `conda uninstall keras`. Then, in the `anaconda3` directory, search "keras" and delete all results. Lastly, run `conda install -c conda-forge keras`, which should download version 2.3.1. You might need to run similar steps with TensorFlow (in fact, it's better you *do*, and first reinstall TensorFlow *then* Keras).

P.S., your code is probably `from keras import Sequential`, as `sequential` should error differently.